# XML Tools in Notepad++: Count on xPath unavailable?

Tags: xml, xpath, count, notepad++

I am trying to evaluate the count of an xPath expression in Notepad++ using XML Tools. Unfortunately, I get the error message by the plugin "Error: error on XPath expression".

Screenshot:
[image]

The sample data/file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk102">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
        <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk103">
        <author>Corets, Eva</author>
        <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
        <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

The goal is, to count the number of books. Any idea why my expression is not working? Is count() not supported? Thank you for any insight!

Note: I know that for this simple case, one could just use the search/count function. But my intention is, to use the count()-function on more complicated xPath expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still seems to be broken. I ended up using VS Code with the [XML Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DotJoshJohnson.xml) extension...works like a charm. Thx for your testing/feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. The plugin is build to return nodes not strings.
Count function is supported (`//book[count(./*)>2]` but you can't use it to return a value.

Possible workaround : use the count function from the search panel with regex option activated.

For example :

```
(?<=Midnight Rain</title>\r\n.{8}).\<genre>
```

Will count the number of "genre" elements after a specific title.

Answer (score -1):

I am using latest version of **Notepad++** v.7.8.5 64-bit, and latest version of the **XML Tools** plugin 3.0.3.4. I am getting the same error like yours.

It seems like a bug in the plugin.